# Files tags and comments in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a VSCode extension or setting which would allow using tags and comments for files?
Or – perhaps – group files by specific property you set by your own?

I have pretty large server/client project and sometimes have to work only on small parts of it.
As project gets complicated, one functionality may be spread over many source files (vue component, router, mongo db schemas, etc.) and it is sometimes hard to remember all of parts.

I am looking for a way to mark only specific files related to feature I am working on.
This way I could have files assigned to "groups" like "add user", "manage JSON"…

I was looking for solution but searching for:

- tags - reveals extensions related to "language tags",
- comments - reveals everything related to language specific comments.

…and this is not it, as I need tagging or commenting files without relation to what is inside them. With nice way I could even "tag" binary files.

PS. As last resort I was hoping for support for descript.ion but with no avail.

--
Thank you in advance,
Karol Kaminski aka fenixproductions